# Tweak a macro vba module to paste values only not formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I put together a macro that will search through a column in a table I have and ONLY copy-paste the rows of that table which have a numerical value in that column onto the next sheet of the spreadsheet. This happens once a button is pressed. My code is as follows:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
End With

'endRow = 20 of course it's best to retrieve the last used row number via a function
pasteRowIndex = 1

For r = 2 To LastCellRowNumber 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, Columns("E").Column).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(r, Columns("E").Column).Value) Then 'Found

            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1

           'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

This works but my problem with it is that it copies the rows with their formulas (which become unusable once copied), so I needed some sort of paste special to only copy the values. I tried this but either keep getting errors or it doesn't work the same way.. can someone please check it for me and point me in the right direction?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, Location As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
End With

pasteRowIndex = 1

For r = 2 To LastCellRowNumber 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, Columns("E").Column).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(r, Columns("E").Column).Value) Then 'Found

            Location = 1
            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Location, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
            Location = Location + 1
           'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Location, 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

You cannot nest Cells (singly) within Range - Cells is already a Range:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Location, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried that just now but it seems to be pasting all the rows in the same row (row 1) on Sheet 2 and they just overwrite eachother leaving me with just the last row.. Is there a way for me to get it to paste the first row at the top and then paste the second row under it and so on?

Comment: You are re-setting Location to 1 each time. Move the line `Location = 1` before the `For r = 2..` line.